# Why is Salesforce example for package.xml manifest files referencing http links instead of https links?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli, package.xml, retrieve, manifest

In [Salesforce help article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm), all their links are referencing the `http` link like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>60.0</version>
</Package>
```

I tested retrieval and deployment using `https` and it is working the same.

However for security purposes, shouldn't they be recommending using `https` protocol instead of `http` ??

Does it matter? Why or why not?

Comment: Those are purely XML namespace URIs. These do not actually have to be URLs at all and need not be accessible over the Internet since they merely provide a unique identifier for the schema.

Answer (score 1):

XML namespaces were intended to uniquely identify an element as belonging to a certain schema in a document where multiple schemas may exist. The *de facto* standard for XML and HTML is to use URI-looking namespaces, but they can be any valid XML string.

Public schemas, like [SVG](http://www.w3.org/2000/svg) (`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`), often point to a real file. This is a convenience to verify that you're using the correct schema. The file might be a page that links to more information, or it might be more like XHTML Strict [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd) (`http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd`) that be applied to a XML file to machine-verify its validity. However, this isn't a rule.

However, I'd consider a value like this to be a [magic switch](http://catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html). You can't assume that some system somewhere won't suddenly crash/error/whatever if you mess with the string. The namespace *is* `http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata`, and any deviation from that namespace is literally referencing a different schema. Better to just leave it alone. And, as Phil said, it's not a real file, so there's no need for security.